# Waiting progress bar in android

Tags: android, progress-bar, progressdialog, android-progressbar

In my android application, I copy some data from server database to local database. The code is posted below. It may take over 15 minutes. For slower connections, it may be exceeded. So I want to display a waiting progress bar that should display "please wait" until the task is finished. I refer many thing, but I couldn't understand how to use the waiting progress bar in the following code.

```
refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View v) {
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
    mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();
    radapter.openToWrite();
    radapter.deleteAll();
    uadapter.openToWrite();
    uadapter.deleteAll();
            try
                {
                     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                      is = entity.getContent();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    json = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                try {
                    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    contacts = jObj.getJSONArray("get");
                    for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                        if(!c.isNull("rname"))// || c.getString("rcode").equals(null))
                        {
                            rname = c.getString("rname");
                            rcode = c.getString("rcode");
                            radapter.insert(rcode, rname);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rname = "";
                            rcode = c.getString("rcode");
                            radapter.insert(rcode, rname);
                        }
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Ryot BackUp completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                adapter.deleteAll();
                oadapter.deleteAll();
                e2.setText("Back Up completed");
            }

       });
```

Someone help me please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Learn about Horizontal Progressbar and threading to handle it accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Progress Dialog` to display with text "**Please Wait...**" and implement your code in `thread` as below:

```
      final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please wait...");
      new Thread() {
          public void run() {
                try{
                      //your code here.....
                   } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                   }
                // dismiss the progress dialog
                       progressDialog.dismiss();
                   }
                }.start();
```

Comment: Place that progressDialog outside of OnClickListener

Comment: I've tried my activity name.this instead of this. Now I solved the error and trying to run my app

Comment: It was created, but disappeared suddenly and force close error

Comment: Note the progressDialog.dismiss(); will close the dialog. So if you using a callback in your code, dismiss it their + in catch block. It took me couple of minutes to understand why the Dialog not opens.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an AsyncTask and update using the onProgressUpdate method